# Attempting to re-run cron while it is already running

Tags: cron

I have a major problem with my system's cron; it runs every 3 minustes causing a slow responding from the site. When I checked the logs, I found this error:

> Attempting to re-run cron while it is already running.

I found some good answers on [Cron stopped running; logs say: "Attempting to re-run cron while it is already running."](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/17264/7-cron-stopped-running-logs-say-attempting-to-re-run-cron-while-it-is-alread) but when I searched for the cron_semaphore variable in variable's table I didn't find it.
Even after I disabled the Search module, and uninstalled it, nothing happened: The cron tasks are still not working.

I checked, and I noticed that the cron tasks have been executed 1 day and 7 hours ago, although I configured it to run every 12 hours.

I am using Drupal 7.19.